# Upload multiple images in Sonata Admin Symfony 4.2

Tags: image, sonata-admin, vichuploaderbundle, symfony-4.2

I'm trying to build a CRUD function in Sonata Admin and want to upload images at Product Admin (not Image Admin). But I got this error and didn't know why when I click Edit:

> Mapping not found for field "images"

I'm new in Symfony. I uploaded image successfully at Image Admin but I dont know how to upload at Product Admin and upload many images at the same time. Here is my code:

One Product has many Images so below is my Product, Image Entity and Product Admin

Product.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ProductRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Image", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $images;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getName();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return Collection|Image[]
     */
    public function getImages(): Collection
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    public function addImage(Image $image): self
    {
        if (!$this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->images[] = $image;
            $image->setProduct($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeImage(Image $image): self
    {
        if ($this->images->contains($image)) {
            $this->images->removeElement($image);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($image->getProduct() === $this) {
                $image->setProduct(null);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Image.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Vich\UploaderBundle\Mapping\Annotation as Vich;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ImageRepository")
 * @Vich\Uploadable
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @var string $name
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     * @var string $path
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product", inversedBy="images")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_images", fileNameProperty="path")
     * @var File $imageFile
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var \DateTime $updatedAt
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }

    /**
     * @param File|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile
     */
    public function setImageFile(File $path = null) : void
    {
        $this->imageFile = $path;
        if($path){
            $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now');
        }
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->getName();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    public function setPath($path): self
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProduct(): ?Product
    {
        return $this->product;
    }

    public function setProduct(?Product $product): self
    {
        $this->product = $product;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

ProductAdmin.php

```
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper): void
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('name')
            ->add('images', VichFileType::class, [
                'label' => 'Image',
                'mapped' => true,
            ])
            ;
    }
```